# Creating an array of objects with txt file values

Tags: java, arrays

I have a txt object with 39 values separated by newlines (enter)
So far I made a class called survey which can get a value at any index in the array called Survey.
for example

```
Survey s1 = new Survey();
System.out.println(s1.getValue(1));
```

output is 3051.0

My question is how would someone go about making an array list which contains Objects which use the sets of values I have. (each object takes 3 consecutive values)

Also what do you use to create a table in java?

Comment: *Also what do you use to create a table in java?* that's way too broad for a question... please add more details, what do you mean by `table`? a 2d array? a list of lists? a table in GUI? what GUI? console? swing? web? ... and No, the output should be [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe_and_Everything_.2842.29)

Comment: Simple printed output for the data in the array but organized into a table. That is what my parameters are.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly want to read up about the `Collection` classes in `java.util`. There are classes that match or contain the words that you mentioned are looking for: `ArrayList` (for array list) and `Hashtable` (for table). Although, in case of `Hashtable` you probably want to use the newer `HashMap` instead.